# Ubuntu Server network setup help

Tags: networking, server, subnet

I have been working for hours trying to figure this out but the installer wants some sub net format I don't understand and google can't provide and clean and clear answer to. I've never dealt with a format in like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy in Windows and the sub net calculators don't provide working values in that format that work. I have literally not even gotten to disk partitioning yet because I can't figure out what its asking for.

Here are the facts.

```
    - This poweredge is has 4 NIC's that are going to be.
    - 10.0.0.10
    - 10.0.0.11
    - 10.0.0.12
    - 10.0.0.13

    - My second server also has 4 NIC's that are going to be. 
    -10.0.0.14 thu you probably guessed 10.0.0.18
    - My default gateway is 10.0.0.1
```

My Windows machine is currently 10.0.0.200 but 
        - should transition to 10.0.0.20 and DHCP should populate from there once I've gotten everything else finished its getting a reload.

Is always a combination of the following failure.

'10.0.0.10' is not contained in '255.0.0.0/8

or

255.0.0.0/1 or 255.0.0.0/0 has host bits set

I can't get the installer past this step. Does anybody have any suggestions? None of this is making any sense to me so I am probably just reading it wrong.

[IP calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITOkX.png)  &  [ubuntu setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwdcd.png)  & [Windows IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmUoR.png)

Thoughts on trying Linux . . . 
I'm trying to learn something new to get out of the world of Windows and I tried Linux years ago only to give up frustrated because of issues just like this, I never could get it installed much less use it. The x11 desktop would always have strange issues where it would never work that I just didn't understand how to fix or the fact once it finally just worked once day after reloading 4 times in a day I never got it to do simple things like share files with Windows computers before it crashed yet again. The command line is an antique of the 80's and while still will always be useful the mouse was invented for a reason, its time for Linux distros to step up and provide and simple GUI. This CLI crap is hard when your old with arthritis and hours of repeated typing yields absolutely nothing but high blood pressure and homicidal rage.

Comment: Windows appears to be set up with 255.255.255.0/24. I suggest that you try that. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu,

Comment: In your 2nd link, the "ubuntu setup" one change `subnet` to `10.0.0.0/24`. You can change the 24 to whatever you actually need greater than or equal to 8. On the subject of the CLI, please know that server people want it that way, because we do not want any extra tasks running. If you want a GUI you can add a desktop GUI and still do server stuff.